# Переход на OpenSource

Tags: linux, active-directory, opensource, samba

Доброго дня. Работаю системным администратором в гос. структуре. Нам поставили задачу "перенести" инфраструктуру на опенсорсные решения, а именно AD и Exchange. Более 1500 пользователей. С линухами работаю относительно недавно, и соответственно, малоопытный. 
Для решения задачи пытался поставить Samba4 **в роли контроллера домена** и привязать всех пользователей к OpenLDAP на Debian 8. Ничего не вышло. Эти двое видимо не дружат, так по крайней мере написано на [Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_LDAP).
А вообще, что нам требуется от контроллера домена:

1. **Пользователи** (Win 7 и XP, планируется в будущем постепенный перевод пользователей на линукс машины) распределены **по поддоменам** (*region.asdf.com,

   city.asdf.com, office.asdf.com* и т.д.)
2. Доступ к сетевым **принтерам** в домене.
3. Общие папки и расшаренные папки на компах пользователей (доступ через "Сетевое окружение" на винде)
4. Групповые политики.

Samba вроде как всё это умеет, по описанию.. но без LDAP он не нужен..

А вместо Exchange хотим поставить почтовик с веб клиентом и отучить пользователей от Outlook.

Так вот, в связи с этим вопрос... Это осущесвимо на линуксе или всё это волшебный мир с единорогами? Начальство ясно дало понять, что денег на лицензию майкрософту не дадут, из-за этого и переход на опенсорс... -_-

Comment: Странно, закупки есть, а софта нет.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeIPA - сам не ковырял, но вроде как даже как-то работает

Answer (score 3):

Я не сисадмин, но на люнихе живу уже почти 20 лет и моё мнение таково:

Когда кто-то пытается перейти на  "опенсорсные решения", то самое первое и (казалось бы) самое естественное - попытаться перенести всё, как есть, используя аналоги из люниха. В первую очередь - самбу. Т.е. смоделировать винду на люнихе. Я убеждён, что это - самый тяжёлый и неэффективный путь.

Рабочие группы, AD и прочие "гениальные" изобретения Билла Гейтса никак не вписываются в идеологию *NIX систем. Достаточно вспомнить такие проблемы, как :

- Разный подход к использованию  имён файлов и каталогов
- Разных подход к понятию "пользователь" и его права
- Разный подход к понятию "свойства (режим)" файла / каталога.

Ну и так далее... Выполнить адекватный перенос очень сложно! Гораздо проще забить на все эти рабочие группы и AD и использовать нативные возможности люниха - файловую систему NFS (которая позволит создавать сетевые структуры гораздо более простыми методами) и права пользователей, предоставляемые самим люнихом. Если у Вас какая-то супер-безопасная контора, можно использовать Linux SE (Например: https://xakep.ru/2015/09/15/astra-linux-se/). Это даст Вам уровень безопасности намного превышающий виндовозный.

Если Вам нужен стандартный набор сетевых сервисов, сделайте один сервер под nas4free (https://www.gotoadm.ru/network-storage-using-nas4free-part-1-installation/) - там одним щелчком запускаются все типовые сервисы:

- Файловая помойка с любым уровнем RAID
- FTP сервер
- WEB сервер
- Самба контроллер
- Почтовый сервер
- ...

Я не помню, что там ещё.

Короче : продумайте структуру системы и сделайте всё с нуля!

Comment: Сложно не согласится :) Но справедливости ради -  некоторые Linux фичи никогда не попадут в лапы Билли ) несмотря на попытки Windows 10 вписать в свою архитектуру docker таким хитропопым способом

Comment: Пользуясь случаем спрошу)
Какой дистрибутив лучше всего подойдет для пользователей? Нужен только офисный пакет и почта, мультимедиа опциональна. Кроме этого у нас еще пара самописных программ, которые нужно будет портировать на линуху.
Главное чтоб стабильно работала, чтоб пользователи меньше мозги нам трепали.

Comment: @ГуломАлимов тот, который легче поддерживать вам и вашему окружению, а также тот, по которому вы найдёте советов и ответов у условного соседа по дому.

Comment: **Какой дистрибутив лучше всего подойдет для пользователей?** - до недавнего времени ответ был очевиден - Ubuntu. Именно там всегда придавали первостепенное значение именно удобству пользователей. Но сейчас это уже не так... История с новым "плиточным" интерфейсом сильно подорвала авторитет Ubuntu. Общая рекомендация такая: ставьте тот дистрибутив, который сегодня пользуется наибольшей популярностью. Это даст Вам максимальное количество коллег, а значит - информации.  Ну вот так, к примеру:
http://ichip.ru/top-10-samykh-populyarnykh-distributivov-linux.html

Comment: А как обстоят дела с вредоносами на пользовательских машинках? Есть ли смысл подыскивать антивирусы или подобное?
На сколько мне известно "по слухам", то на линухе вирусов нет, но в это мне не верится.. Буду рад прояснению :)

Comment: **как обстоят дела с вредоносами на пользовательских машинках?** - лично я за 20 лет работы на линухе ни разу не сталкивался. Хотя не пользовался никакими анитивирусами и на шлюзе у меня ничего такого не стоит.

Comment: **Есть ли смысл подыскивать антивирусы или подобное?** - имеет смысл, если у вас будет стоять почтовый сервер. Вот на нём надо ставит. сканер писем. Иначе Ваш почтовик может послужить передаточным пунктом для рассылки заражённых писем.

Comment: **на линухе вирусов нет, но в это мне не верится.** - на самом деле - есть! Т.н. "олбанские".  Это когда Вы читаете письмо, а там написано: "Мы - крутые олбанские хакеры, требуем с Вас 100 баксов! Если Вы не заплатите нам эти 100 баксов, то тогда зайдите в командную строку и выполните команду del * . *".  Ну, против настолько крутых хакеров - люних бессилен :-(

Comment: Имея скромный опыт (4 предприятия с "0" под OpenSource, не считая школ, скажу так. Как файловый сервер Самба пока вне конкуренции, настраивается вполне достаточно для работы. Не рекомендуется создавать расшаренные папки у пользователей, приучайте работать только с сервером и на нем выделять индивидуально или групповой доступ. Будет проще сопровождать и бакапить добро пользователей. Что касается простого почтового сервера быстро и удобно то **[Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/documentation:cmdman:citserver)** решит вашу проблему на 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день!
То что пишу - сугубо мое мнение. На вашем месте я бы использовал Samba(https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller) в качестве контроллера домена управлять можно из mmc консоли установив RSAT для windows. Если на сервере то для создания\удаления и редактирования пользователей phpldapadmin можно использовать.

С exchange посложнее но есть вариант развернуть на схему SAMBA AD DC - openchange (правда проект вроде как закрылся) или как вариант посмотреть в сторону SOGo (https://sogo.nu/) в качестве фронтенда для postfix(или exim кому как удобнее)\dovecot.

Есть еще kolab (https://kolab.org/) он в себе содержит DirSrv(это реализация LDAP) почтовик(postfix\dovecot\spamassasin\postgrey) и в качестве фронтенда - roundcube

Но самый простой вариант для вас взять Zentyal он на убунте с самбой все в нем и почтовик и прокси и сого и файерволл.

А вообще начинание крутое! успехов! (подумайте сразу чем можно MS Office заменить)

Comment: Если использовать KUbuntu, то там из коробки едёт LibreOffice. Хотя, если честно, до МС-офиса не дотягивает (пока не дотягивает), но вполне ничё так.

Comment: Да есть еще WPS Office и это все крутые продукты, но к примеру для меня очень сложно заменить Visio хоть я и под линухом только сижу (приходится на VirtualBox использовать MS Visio)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) 
А на счёт офиса рано волноваться, это меньшая из проблем сейчас :)

Comment: Visio? [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/)!

Comment: PlantUML - посмотрю, но что-то сомневаюсь что там будет подобие VisioCafe с возможностью нарисовать стойку в серверной, но спасибо!